# Mesh analysis with common voltage source?

Tags: circuit-analysis

What happens if I have a dependent voltage source common between two meshes? Do I need to form a supermesh or is it okay the way I solved it?[image]

Comment: Supermeshes are needed for current sources, not voltage sources.

Comment: Okay, so... They way I solved this, is it okay?

Comment: It's easy to check your own work: Do you get the same voltage at each node regardless of which path from ground you sum up to get there? Are the currents and voltages for each branch consistent with the device on that branch?

Comment: Obtain the mesh current in the circuit of the figure posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mesh analysis involves equations with voltages, the need for supermesh analysis arises only when you come across a current source in the mesh. This is because voltage across a current source can't be found directly.

So the way you have solved it is perfectly okay.